# Which linux kernel version I'm using with yocto poky SUMO branch?

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto

I am using yocto project to build linux kernel for my board.
I used yocto project version 2.5 SUMO branch and 19.0 poky version.
I am going to use MUSL-LibC and this is dependent to Linux 2.6 or later versions as it's shown here : 
https://www.musl-libc.org/faq.html

I want to know how can I find out which linux kernel version I'm using now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your BSP layer you'll find the following parameter:

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-yocto ??= "5.0%"
```

You can check recipes for which kernel version it provides in `recipes-kernel/linux`.

Also, look for `kernel-*` packages in `./tmp/deploy/rpm/`.

Answer (score 1):

Well the linux kernel version depends not only of the BSP layer   provided by your embedded device. Actually there are different layers that may overwrite your current kernel version.

here I list few of them:

1. meta-linaro
2. meta-openembedded
3. meta-board-name *this i believe is the most relevant*

to see the complete list use the following command

```
bitbake-layers show-recipes 'linux*'
```

So, I suggest you look for the kernel as a following

```
cd <yocto_root_folder>
grep -r "LINUX_VERSION"
```

The command above will list the all the layers that overwrite the Linux kernel version. You should pay more attention in those that have something like "recipes-kernel". In specific, those related to your board.

here some examples

*meta-linaro/meta-linaro-integration/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto-tiny_3.17.bb:LINUX_VERSION ?= "3.17.8"*

*meta-renesas/meta-rcar-gen3/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-renesas_4.14.bb:PV = "${LINUX_VERSION}+git${SRCPV}"*

**Since my board is renesas I will assume the kernel version is 4.14.**

you can force yocto to compile an specific kernel version using the following command:

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-yocto ??= "<version>%"
```

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Linux_Yocto

Yocto Project Release =
Yocto Project 2.5

LTSI Kernel Version =
linux-yocto_4.9

LTS Kernel Version =
linux-yocto_4.14

Released Kernel Version =
linux-yocto_4.15